# button inside gridLayout too small

Tags: android

When I add  grid layout, I always encounter the same issue.

Here is my code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="258dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
    app:columnCount="2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:rowCount="2">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Here is an image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your code like this below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
android:layout_width="368dp"
android:layout_height="258dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
android:columnCount="2"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
android:rowCount="2">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

the changes i made `android:columnCount="2"
android:rowCount="2"`

Comment: i get these  ![errors](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cz765m8swztf2md/android.jpg?dl=0).

Comment: @zouve Change your `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` to just `GridLayout`